# How many number of samples must be taken to ensure no information is lost in normalization?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

I was using nn.LayerNorm from Pytorch to normalize my dataset. I tested on a tensor of two points but surprisingly found that my output is almost always the same. Going off the equation of normalization, I find that the standard deviation cancels out the mean, and I am left with only 1 or -1. How can I ensure that no information is lost during normalization? How many samples do I need?